# What is the expectation value of the number operator on the generalized squeeze state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

Consider a generalized squeezed state defined by $|\alpha,γ \rangle$ to be $D(\alpha)S(γ)|0\rangle$ .
So, the expectation value of $\hat{N}$ (which is $a^\dagger a$) would be
$$\langle 0 | S^\dagger(γ)D^\dagger(\alpha)\hat{N}D(\alpha)S(γ)|0\rangle = \langle 0|S^\dagger(γ)D^\dagger(\alpha)a^\dagger a D(\alpha)S(γ)|0\rangle \, .$$

I do not know where to go from here, given that
\begin{align}
S^\dagger(γ)a S(γ) &= \cosh (γ) a − \sinh (γ) a^\dagger \\
D^\dagger(\alpha) a D(\alpha) &= a + \alpha \, .
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 
$$ D^\dagger(\alpha)aD(\alpha)=a+\alpha\, , \tag{1}
$$ then take transpose conjugate to find 
$$
D^\dagger(\alpha) a^\dagger D(\alpha)=a^\dagger + \alpha^*\, . \tag{2}
$$

Next, note that 
$$
D^\dagger(\alpha) a^\dagger aD(\alpha)= 
D^\dagger(\alpha) a^\dagger D(\alpha)D^\dagger(\alpha) aD(\alpha) \tag{3}
$$
since $D D ^\dagger =\hat 1$.  You can then use (1) and (2) in (3),  sandwich the result of (3) in $S^\dagger$ and $S$, and then evaluate the result between $\langle 0\vert$ and $\vert 0\rangle$.  You might have to use
$$
S(\gamma)S^\dagger(\gamma)=\hat 1\, .
$$

Comment: I.e., just some judicious multiplications by $1$ here and there ;-).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty A large amount of physics reduces to writing $1$ or $\hat 1$ in a judicious way.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Using your advice, I've solved what D†(α)a†aD(α)  is, and I have the S† and S operators around it. I tried solving for what that would be but I'm ending up trying to use cosh(γa) and sinh(γa†) on the |0> state and trying to complex conjugate them(which I'm lost at doing). The answer might be looking at me in my face, but a little help would be appreciated.

Comment: @NameNotFoundException I don’t think the operators are inside the arguments of the hyperbolic functions.

Comment: @NameNotFoundException You're misreading the transformation under $S(\gamma)$. It should read $$S^\dagger(γ)a S(γ) = \cosh(γ) a − \sinh (γ) a^\dagger.$$ Cf. e.g. [Wikipedia's article on the squeeze operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_operator).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to ZeroTheHero's answer, once you've conjugated 
$$ 
D^\dagger(\alpha)aD(\alpha)=a+\alpha\, , \tag{1}
$$
to get 
$$
D^\dagger(\alpha) a^\dagger D(\alpha)=a^\dagger + \alpha^* , \tag{2}
$$
if you want to avoid writing a bunch of operator-inverse pairs, you can just multiply on the left by $D(\alpha)$ to turn both of those into
$$ 
aD(\alpha)=D(\alpha)(a+\alpha)\, \tag{1$'$}
$$
and
$$
a^\dagger D(\alpha)=D(\alpha)(a^\dagger + \alpha^* ) \tag{2$'$}
$$
(with similar versions for $S(\gamma)a$ and $S(\gamma)a^\dagger$), and you can work your way left (or right) from there.